# plugin for converting OScommerce site to facebook store

Tags: facebook, oscommerce

How can i convert my OScommerce site to facebook store? Please suggest me a good plugin for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This addon is a simple addon which can help to bring your site live into face book.Click this [link](http://addons.oscommerce.com/info/7814) for more information regarding this plugin.